# Do WiFi / Bluetooth use sine wave or square wave?

Tags: wifi

WiFi and Bluetooth use 2.4 GHz band. Do they use sine wave or square wave?

Comment: PkP basically gave the correct answer. The link he posted gives more detail on the topic. You can safely assume that NO radio transmission uses a square wave as a carrier signal, as it has infinite bandwidth, and thus would interfere with all other bands, making it essentially illegal. Older Wi-Fi Standards use QPSK, newer ones OFDM, which you can think of being modulated around a sine wave near the channel's frequency.

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research.

Answer (score 4):

Neither. They use spread spectrum signaling.

If you want to try to "visualize in your head" what spread spectrum signaling means, you can think of it as a certain kind of "hiss" or "noise" in a frequency band of a couple of megahertz in the 2.4GHz range. Obviusly it's not noise, as it's very specifically defined signal, but it would sound more or less like noise if you could hear it.

https://superuser.com/questions/298568/how-does-wi-fi-modulate-the-electro-magnetic-wave

Comment: I am not asking about type of modulation. I am talking about shape of the carrier wave.

Comment: "It's basically just noise". Please explain this.

Comment: Well, if you really want to think in terms of carrier waves etc, then you obviously would have a sine wave. But it's modulated so quickly that it loses so much resemblence to sine that it becomes more like noise. But of course, Wi-Fi has many signaling methods for different speed ranges. etc... my answer is not very thorough. But certainly it's not square wave, what would be the point in using that?